# Leopard gecko seems sick

Tags: behavior, reptiles, leopard-geckos, anxiety, lizards

Just a few nights of having our baby leopard gecko, the poor thing escaped because we did not have access to an appropriate tank until a few days later. After an hour of searching, we found it under a bookshelf with its tail missing and its arm broken up. We got a vet's help and it has been doing well recovering, with a fully grown-back tail and half of the broken arm, which is concerning.

Now, it has been a few months since then, but something off is happening. (his or her) once yellow body is now an odd brown color, and it seems that there are more spots around the mouth than normal. Also, I will hear it scream and go to check on it, and the poor little thing will be licking its bottom? Eating, drinking and temperatures are normal, but it seems stressed and jumpy. Can someone please tell me what is happening to my gecko?

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons for all of these symptoms (spots around the mouth could be mouth rot, going a different colour could mean she's too cold, licking her butt can be normal but if she's doing it very regularly it could be irritation from worms or something), this combined with the fact she is stressed and jumpy points to the fact that she isn't well. I think you should take her to a vet.